# Does Android platform support SpatiaLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, geospatial

Is it possible to use SpatiaLite database on Android platform (1.6)? I am trying to program a google buzz-like app which need to take advantage of SpatiaLite functions, like calculating distance between 2 points, etc. Any external library needed? Thanks.

Comment: I've never used SpatiaLite, so I may be asking a dumb question, but why are the built in location based classes not sufficient?

Comment: That's a solution too. I just think there might be a better way by using spatial database. So the distance info may be able calculated or index in advance. But I have no idea how that works though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my guess would be that someone would have to compile spatialite to work on the android linux version. And then you would have to get it on the phone. I voted up the question because I would love to see it happen.

Answer (score 8):

Spatialite for Android: https://github.com/sevar83/android-spatialite
(disclaimer: I'm the repo's owner)

Another implementation
http://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/

Tutorial on it:
https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial

But I doubt it supports such an outdated version (1.6).

Comment: Hello @WindRider, 

I have implement your code from https://github.com/sevar83/android-spatialite and its integrate as Spatialite DD but not creating DB as SpatialDb.
 fun specialQuery()  {
        var count = 1.123456
        val selectQuery =
            "SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(92.24909721 24.63542998)'),ST_GeomFromText('POINT(91.53909721 23.98742998)')) as cnt;"
        val db: SQLiteDatabase = this.readableDatabase
        val cursor: Cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
        count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("cnt")).toDouble()
    }